# Combobox binding doesn't work unless debug converter is used in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm stumped. I have a `ComboBox` who's `ItemSource` is a custom dictionary called `ObservablePaircollection` which is just an observable dictionary (source code found http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/wpf-editable-datagrid-and.html). The `DisplayMemberPath` is the key of the dictionary, where the `SelectedValuePath` is the value of said key.

I'm reading in a config file, which contains a string that my program matches with a given key, and then populates the combobox with that matching key. The problem is, the combobox always appears empty UNLESS I add in a Converter to the bindings which is just a simple debugconverter that lets me check XAML bindings. I can't figure out why.

Here's the converter:

```
public class DatabindingDebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here's my xaml for the combobox:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Key"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedModel.Fields, Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedField, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

This is the class where the ItemSource comes from, which is called `SelectedModel` (I'll post the class for that after this):

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ModelBase _selectedModel;
    public ModelBase SelectedModel
    {
        get { return _selectedModel; }
        set { _selectedModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedModel"); }
    }

    private Pair<string, string> _selectedField;
    public Pair<string, string> SelectedField
    {
        get { return _selectedField; }
        set { _selectedField = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedField"); }
    }
}
```

Here's the `ModelBase` class:

```
public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservablePairCollection<string, string> _fields = new ObservablePairCollection<string, string>();
    public ObservablePairCollection<string, string> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
        set { _fields = value; OnPropertyChanged("Fields"); }
    }
}
```

As you can see from my XAML code above, the converter is added in two of the bindings. When I take the converter out, the combobox is no longer properly populated.

Comment: Side note: ItemsSource is `SelectedModel.Fields`. SelectedItem is `SelectedField`. Shouldn't this also be `SelectedModel.SelectedField` ?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using an item template to set how you want the data to be shown,
additionally, if the combobox doesn't know how to handle the data, it'll need a converter.  Does it hurt to just use an empty converter?

Comment: The combobox is actually in an item template, but yeah I guess it doesn't hurt using an empty converter. Still strange that it works like that (to me at least).